# How do i fix this floating label in plain css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

project is here -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/udQSLuVwHa

When i click inside the InputField (do not click directly on the Username label), the Label correctly shrinks.
And if i click out of the inputField (make it lose focus), the Label gets big again.
Now, if i type some text into the InputField, and the make it lose focus, the Username label should not shrink, but stay on top.

I have commented out the CSS that should work.  Its something wrong with my CSS right? and not tailwinds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select `label` when it's sibling `input` is not showing placeholder by `input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label`, here is your styles with new selector:

```
.outline:focus-within label,
input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label {
  background-color: white;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-1rem);
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-left: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 0.25rem;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saeed's answer is a great CSS solution.

If you want to solve this in JavaScript you could do the following:

(note styling will look different when you run code snippet as tailwind isn't present)

```js
inputUsername = document.getElementById('inputUsername');
labelUsername = document.getElementById('labelUsername');

inputUsername.onfocus = () => {
    labelUsername.classList.add('outline');
}

inputUsername.onblur = () => {
    if (inputUsername.value.length == 0){
        labelUsername.classList.remove('outline');
    }
}
```

```css
.outline {
    background-color: white;
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-1rem);
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 0.25rem;
    padding-right: 0.25rem;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outline relative border-2 focus-within:border-blue-500">
    <input id="inputUsername" class="bg-red-700 block p-4 w-full text-lg appearance-none bg-transparent" placeholder=" " type="text" />
    <label id="labelUsername" for="username" class="absolute top-0 text-lg bg-white p-4 -z-1 duration-300 origin-0">Username</label>
  </div>
```